# jQuery: Preserve hover state when coming off element?

Tags: jquery

1.I have 2 menus, "Main" & "Sub" - when you hover over a specific link in the main, it highlights the sub menu by adding a class to it...great... thing is when I roll off the "main li link" the colour of the sub nav goes back to normal... - But I need this preserved if I roll onto the sub nav... e.g. them all highlighted...

1. ...then.... once I actually hover onto the sub nav....then the highlighting would cease...and only the sub menu item link i roll onto goes the highlighted colour (This can just be the normal "a:hover" state.

So I guess in a nutshell..

Hover on a main menu item...the sub-menu items get highlighted... come off the main nav...the sub menu is still highlighted......(though this would only be highlighted if going from main to sub) - anythign else it would loose highlighting) ...then once on sub menu...remove the highlighting (So the standard a:hover for the sub menu get's used...

Here's my code thus far, which activates the global highlighting:

```
<ul id="primarynav">
    <li><a href="">home</a></li>
    <li class="portfolio"><a href="">protfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Secondary nav -->

<ul id="secondarynav">
    <li><a href="">Websites</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Graphics</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Drawing</a></li>
</ul>


$(document).ready(function(){
    var $primarynav = $('#primarynav .portfolio'),
        $secondarynav = $('#secondarynav');

    $primarynav.hover(function(){
        $secondarynav.addClass('highlight');
    }, function(){
        $secondarynav.removeClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
<ul id="primarynav">
    <li><a href="">home</a></li>
    <li class="portfolio"><a href="">protfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Secondary nav -->

<ul id="secondarynav">
    <li><a href="">Websites</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Graphics</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Drawing</a></li>
</ul>


$(document).ready(function(){
    var $primarynav = $('#primarynav .portfolio'),
        $secondarynav = $('#secondarynav');

    $primarynav.hover(function(){
        $secondarynav.addClass('highlight');
    });

    $secondarynav.hover(function(){
        $secondarynav.removeClass('highlight);
    });
});
```

- It highlights the subnav when hovering the main nav
- It doesn't take the highlight away when leaving the main nav
- The
  highlight goes away when hovering the submenu